# How do I create list of point objects?

Tags: python, point

I want to use the following function in my program:

```
def computeVoronoiDiagram(points):
    """ Takes a list of point objects (which must have x and y fields).
Returns a 3-tuple of:

(1) a list of 2-tuples, which are the x,y coordinates of the
Voronoi diagram vertices
(2) a list of 3-tuples (a,b,c) which are the equations of the
lines in the Voronoi diagram: a*x + b*y = c
(3) a list of 3-tuples, (l, v1, v2) representing edges of the
Voronoi diagram. l is the index of the line, v1 and v2 are
the indices of the vetices at the end of the edge. If
v1 or v2 is -1, the line extends to infinity.
"""
    siteList = SiteList(points)
    context = Context()
    voronoi(siteList,context)
    return (context.vertices,context.lines,context.edges)
```

It says take a list of point objects (which have x & y field). Is it different than Python Lists data structures? How do I create such a object?
Edit: I should mention list would contain about million random points.

Comment: Usually points are represented as tuples: `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]`.

Comment: @moooeeeep This is the library: https://github.com/rougier/gallery/blob/master/voronoi/voronoi/voronoi.py

Comment: I had replied with a solution for [this other library](https://svn.osgeo.org/qgis/branches/Release-1_6_0/python/plugins/fTools/tools/voronoi.py), which seems to be the one in your question. Why the discrepancy? This one from github does not include the code you posted.

Comment: `from collections import namedtuple; Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'], verbose=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Does the library you're using contain a Point class?

If not:

```
 from collections import namedtuple
 Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x','y'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;

def main():
    pointslist = [Point(0, 0)] * 10
    mytuple = computeVoronoiDiagram(pointslist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Obviously you'd need the rest of the code for `computeVoronoiDiagram()` and supporting code, and sounds like you'd want to randomize the `x` and `y` coords of each point, instead of setting them all to `0`.

Comment: @moooeeeep: Err, yes, maybe. Edited.